# R: Datapoints every 5 minutes over some years -> summary over time of day

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have data.frames in R containing values measured in an interval of 5 minutes. Its a huge amount of data (~2mio).

```
 date                    close     day
73 2015-01-02 00:05:00 0.00861385   0
74 2015-01-02 00:10:00 0.00861385   0
75 2015-01-02 00:15:00 0.00861385   0
```

I want to group the data by the daytime. For example adding the value "close" from 2015-01-02 00:05:00 to the "close" value from 2015-02-02 00:05:00 and so on...

I'm pretty sure its easy to manage, but I don't know the search terms I have to google. Any breadcrumbs would be highly appreciated.

PS: It would be cool, if there are any solutions avoiding loops, because they are very slow in R

Comment: I think you need `cumsum` but provide data with `dput` and a more detailed expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with library(data.table).

with your dataset as `df` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)                             # set your data.frame to data.table
df[, mins := .GRP, minute(date)]      # group by minutes of your 'date' field
df[, .(sums = sum(close)), by=mins]   # sum by group
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!